# CSS or JQuery animation

Tags: jquery, css

http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone/

Any idea on the best way to achieve this kind of animation with images flying in and then flying out? I know you can animate with CSS and assume this is most likely what Apple used in this case...

Comment: Apparently Apple uses prototype and scriptaculous for some of the animation duties. But after looking at it on IE9 and FF7 I'm guessing the actual animated movements are CSS transforms. Apple appears to fall back to a simple fade effect when transforms aren't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by “best”. CSS animations and transitions are likely to use up fewer CPU cycles, but they’re not supported by older versions of browsers (e.g. IE 8).

Coincidentally, I just saw an article explaining how Apple’s iPhone 4S CSS animations work:

- http://johnbhall.com/iphone-4s/

Comment: @Andy: now it depends what you mean by “results”. If you don’t tell us what criteria you value, we don’t know what satisfies them.

Comment: Appearance. Regardless, the explanation via that article does a pretty good job of demonstrating how it is done. Thanks for the linkage.

Comment: @Andy: gotcha. CSS animations and transitions should reliably look better (i.e. run smoother), but obviously only in browsers that support them.

Answer (score 1):

For cross browser compatibily you can use [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/), which incorporates a small animation library. With Raphael you can rotate, fade, ... your images.

If you target only *modern browsers*, you can use CSS3 transisitons and transforms which perform better in general, because they can be hardware accelerated. [Introduction to CSS3 Transitions, Transforms](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/)

Comment: Yep, transitions and transforms are where it's at. Thanks for linking to my tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no JQuery, but then again, JQuery is just Javascript, so Apple might very well have written their own. 
Anyway, it is indeed animated using Javascript and CSS.

The only alternatives to these would be to use video (which it isn't), animated GIF (not very likely as well), or Flash, which would be rather silly on an Apple website.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for :

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Used of the fadeIn and fadeOut jQuery function, when you click on the next button of the gallery.

If you want to do it in jquery ;)

Comment: I want it to happen naturally rather than having to initiate it by clicking the next button.

Comment: You could do it with a combination of a timer : setTimeout() in javascript

Comment: The fade only happens on old browsers, newer ones get a fancy animation.